# launching email client from my app(android)

Tags: android, android-intent

hi i have used the following code to launch an email client but it is launching only messaging app...so what should get modified in this code....

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"vgsl.manju@gmail.com"});
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send a mail ..."));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code snippet looks fine. 
Try it on an actual device, it should work fine.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work on emulator but did it fine on a real one !

Answer (score 1):

```
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Try this, it works on me.

Answer (score 0):

first check if your email client is configured.